# Pop up - Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am trying to implement login with paypal, I have 2 different host domains

**1- www.example.com**

**2- www.example.de**

For paypal I need to choose a return URL for this purpose I choosed www.example.com/callbackfrompaypal

so in my callbackfrompaypal

```
 if (!redirectUrl.Host.Equals(_dependencies.HttpRequestContextService.Request.Url.Host, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) //return back orginal domain
 {
     return View(redirectUrl); //If uri host is different than user's host turn back to user's host
 }
```

redirect Url is an URI which is created with the return domain[query parameter and could get the orginal host]

so if user enters from  www.example.de and try to login with, paypal going to call me back like that

**www.example.com/callbackfrompaypal?redirectUrl=www.example.de**

Then  I compare redirect URL and current URL and if they are not same, I will redirect

**www.example.de/callbackfrompaypal?redirectUrl=www.asdasd.de**

but it will be done in POP UP and as you guys guess BROWSERS telling me that Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.example.com" from accessing a frame with origin" https://www.example.de"

can you guys show me a way to how to fix this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a security measure, **you really can't** use Javascript to access a frame with content from a different site, that would be a huge security flaw.

If you want to do this you'll have to reload the page on your **.com** domain before using paypal, otherwise you'll need to store informations on your server and then redirect to the **.com** domain, but I recommend you the first option.

Comment: as you said you are right, what I am doing is now, closing pop up then redirect the parent window and it works, thank you